# get a value of string with beautiful soup using python

Tags: python

I've made a script that extracts texts from forum website, there's no problem with it but I want to get a value of the string which user posted, for example, see below

```
s = "(Username[^\"]+)(?:<div>)"
r = requests.get("https://example.com/threads/73956/page2", headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
result = re.findall(s, r.text)
print(result[0].replace("<br />", ""))
```

I want the value of string number which is 2

```
<div class="wwCommentBody">
     <blockquote class="postcontent restore " style="padding: 10px;">Username: 
     leetibrahim<br>
    Number: 2       
     </blockquote>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the problem you're having?

Comment: @enzo there's nothing about it, I just want to add a variable that extracts the value of `number` which is `2`, so how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should yield the number string:

```
n_str = r"(?<=Number:)(.+)"
r = requests.get("https://ffs.gg/threads/73956/page2", headers=headers, cookies=cookies)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
result = re.findall(n_str, r.text)
print(result[0])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! last thing please, I used your code but there's a space before the username value, how can I remove it?
` Marvel`

Comment: @Marvel you can always use .strip() on any string to remove trailing / leading spaces. https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp

Comment: I did this but it dosen't work `x = n_str.strip()`

Comment: @Marvel you would need to use it on the obtained string. For instance, if you get the result, then you can say username = result[0].strip(). The answer for the query (searching using regex) is returned in the result variable. Then by using [0] you access the first group found (the username / string). This is the actual string you print (and therefore is the one that needs .strip() at the end).